# jQuery AJAX can't work with JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON response from my php file like:

```
[
  {"id":"1"},
  {"archiveitem":"<small>26.06.2015 12:25<\/small><br \/><span class=\"label label-default\">Bug<\/span> has been submitted by Admin"}
]
```

And try to fetch this response into a div after button was clicked, however firebug is telling me the message from the error-handler. I can't figure out the problem?

```
$('#loadarchive').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/src/php/LoadAdminDashboardArchive.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action : 'getArchive'
        },
        success: function(results) {
            var archiveelements = JSON.parse(results);
            console.log(results);
            $.each(archiveelements, function(){
                $('#archivecontent').html('<div class="mark-read-container"><span class="btn-mark-unread" id="' + this.id + '">Unarchive</span></div><div class="bs-callout bs-callout-default">' + this.archiveitem + '</div>');
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Cannot retrieve data.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If the error handler is hit it means the response from the server is not `200 OK`. This means there's an error in your `responseURL` location. In fact, if `responseURL` is a variable, you should remove the quotes around it.

Comment: What's the HTTP status code for this response?

Comment: Wow, that was fast :-) I am not very familiar with firebug, but it seems as it is not giving any response... The responseURL is not a variable it's just /src/php/LoadAdminDashboardArchive.php

Comment: I'm sorry, code above has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working and the problem was quite simple...

I forgot to paste the "button" - source code that initiated the ajax request. It was an Input of type "submit" and therefore the page reloaded by default after the response was retrieved successfully... so e.preventDefault(); was the way to go.

Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run your Code and I get

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

By defining `dataType: 'json'` your result is parsed already as an Array. So you can do something like:

```
success: function (results) {
    if (results["head"]["foo"] != 0) {
        // do something
    } else if (results["head"]["bar"] == 1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

this works on my computer:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/src/php/LoadAdminDashboardArchive.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { action : 'getArchive' },
    success: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        $.each(results, function(){
            $('#archivecontent').html('<div class="mark-read-container"><span class="btn-mark-unread" id="' + this.id + '">Unarchive</span></div><div class="bs-callout bs-callout-default">' + this.archiveitem + '</div>');
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('Cannot retrieve data.');
    }
});
```

Comment: What tool is giving you that "syntax error" ? I don't see that in firebug.. Even using your code, I get: readyState 0  ResponseJSON undefined status 0 statusText "error"

Comment: I used Firebug 2.0.11 to debug and got this message on the Firebug-console

Comment: probably there is an error in your `/src/php/LoadAdminDashboardArchive.php`-File, what response do you get when you call that URL direct?

Comment: When removing the "isset" handler on the php file and opening the url then I get the json formatted like mentioned above...

Comment: What "isset" do you have?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] == "getArchive"))

Comment: What do you mean with "system"? Another Webserver? Why are you asking, what do you think is the problem?

Comment: The Ajax Code is working in my opinion, the php Script gives you the answer you expect, so probably there is a Problem with the Server or the configuration ;-)

Comment: kamituel asked: What's the HTTP status code for this response?

Comment: You can find the Code in Firebug - > Console and there stands something like `POST http://localhost/foo.ajax.php 999 1ms` what is the 999 in your case?

Comment: That is unfortunately not displaying anything related to the request sent to my php file. It seems like it is just reloading the page. If I filter for xhr-requests the request itself is listed, but there is not http status code returned from it. However, playing around with firebug I found out the following: If I track exucution using the "script" tab and click on the "Pause"-button on the left when there is a small XHR overlay laying over the pause-button - then I can see the the json response is correctly inserted into the div ?! If I continue then the execution it re-disappears?!

Comment: Ok, after checking firebug doc - as soon as I click on "stop at XHR" in the network-tab - I can see the 200 response from my php file and the json response is correctly formatted and pushed into my div

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information from the console if you dive into it a bit more. Or by logging these two parameters:

```
error: function(xhr, mssg) {
    console.log(xhr, mssg);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that... it is giving me:  
 Object { readyState=0,  status=0,  statusText="error",  mehr...} error

Answer (score 1):

**First**
your response is not correct,Correct response should look like this

```
[{
  "id":"1",
  "archiveitem":"<small>26.06.2015 12:25<\/small>
<br \/><span class=\"labellabel-default\">Bug<\/span> has been submitted by Admin"
},
{
  ...
}]
```

**Second** 
You dont have to parse result ie.`JSON.parse` is not required since `dataType:'json'` will probably take care of json.

Finally your success method should look like this:

```
 success: function(results) {
            $.each(results, function(ind,el){
                $('#archivecontent').html('<div class="mark-read-container"><span class="btn-mark-unread" id="' + el.id + '">Unarchive</span></div><div class="bs-callout bs-callout-default">' + el.archiveitem + '</div>');
            });
        },
```

Comment: Ok, I agree the json response was formatted incorrect, I changed it and it is now:
    [{"id":"1","archiveitem":"<small>26.06.2015 12:25<\/small><br \/><span class=\"label label-default\">Bug<\/span> has been submitted by Admin"}]

I also changed the jquery part, but the error is still the same...

Comment: @Quhalix89 use network tab in developer tools and check if the request returns correct response

Comment: When using the network tab in firefox developer tools it seems like clicking the button is only sending a request to the current page instead of my php-json-response-file

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying message from error-handler is showing.

That means AJAX is never sent to server because of incorrect URL or any other reason.

Use Firebug in Firefox and see the error in console tab.

Also I see your code

```
dataType: 'json',
data: { action : 'getArchive' },
success: function(results) {
    var archiveelements = JSON.parse(results);
}
```

Do not use `JSON.parse(results)` because you have already written `dataType: 'json',` and any type of response is parsed automatically.